# Which geometric, rounded, Bauhaus style fonts are similar to this sans-serif 'Abeat by Kai'?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, sans-serif

I'm building an iOS 8 app and would really like to use the font [**A beat by Kai**](http://www.dafont.com/abeatbykai.font) created by [Kai Buskirk](http://kaibuskirk.com/).

Font sample:

[image]

This font is free for personal use but not for commercial use.

I'm wondering how I can buy a license for commercial use on an App in the App Store, or if you can recommend similar fonts that I can use for my apps?

Comment: Please search on this side; there are similar questions were you will find the links to websites to find other fonts ...  BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: keywords i would use to search: geometric, rounded, bauhaus

Comment: @spiral I'll look into those keywords, thanks

Comment: It feels like a really bad version of Avante Garde. But yes, the best way to handle this is to just contact the designer and ask for a commercial license.

Answer (score 5):

[**Comfortaa**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Comfortaa) is a pretty close / similar alternative, if you don't mind the rounded ends, and it's free/open source.

[image]

<sub>It's Comfortaa Regular in the example</sub>

Comment: Though still a little quirky, I'd say this is much better drawn in terms of overall proportions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also contact the designer directly: http://www.dafont.com/profile.php?user=397384

You do need an account.

Comment: Best to use the email address: ContactUs@ABeatByKai.com or send him on a message on that website?

Comment: I think that doesnt matter too much. He will get the message either way. You could also use the form on his website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). It searches similar fonts by image.

Modulus Medium

DyeLine Medium

Ardeco 3

Harry Plain

[image]

Not a perfect match but I wouldn't tell the difference.

Comment: WhatTheFont results do not persist, and your link has expired. You need to link to the individual fonts (and, preferably, include an image of each in your answer).